# Monitoring location updates and significant location updates

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, core-location

Part of my requirements for the app is to track the user when the app is in the foreground or in the background/suspended.

I can do this easily. However, I also have to track their location as they move about even when the app is terminated which requires me to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`

**My Question:**

Is there any drawbacks to enabling GPS location updates *and* significant location changes updates at the same time?

For example:

```
private lazy var locationManager:CLLocationManager = {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    manager.activityType = .Fitness
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    return manager
}()
```

and then somewhere else, I begin updating...

```
func start(){
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}
```

Is it okay to do it like this? Is there anything I should be aware of?

Comment: I'm like 99% sure that there are no drawbacks. One is on a timer, and the other is distance based.

Comment: There is no timer involved in either update. But you can use both at the same time. Using "best for navigation" all the time will drain the battery quite quickly however